# Applications of disjoint unions (or coproducts in general)

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

According to Engelking (General Topology, p. 76), results regarding disjoint unions are usually very easy to prove and belong to "topological folklore." Most topology textbooks show some rather trivial results regarding disjoint unions, for example:

- disjoint union is a coproduct in the category of topological spaces
- a set is closed in the disjoint union if and only if its intersection with each individual space is closed in that space
- Disjoint union is Hausdorff if and only if each individual space is

I was wondering what were some other interesting (preferably not as trivial as the above) results that use disjoint unions (or coproducts in general).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean results *about* disjoint unions or *applications* of disjoint unions in topological constructions?

Comment: @PaulFrost Both

Comment: In order for this question not to be too broad, you may want to be a bit more specific about what you want. There are topological facts involving disjoint unions that aren’t categorical facts about the disjoint union, so you’re asking two different questions here: one topological and one categorical.

Comment: @SantanaAfton You are right, I am asking 2 questions here. I was hoping for some non-trivial theorems that use disjoint unions or non-trivial theorems that use coproducts.